# Can we create TestContext of our own data?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to process the test data from different source(a text file) rather than using `[DataSource]`attribute. I was looking for a way to add the rows of the `DataTable` to `TestContext`which is being created in `[MyAttribute]` which processes the text file.

```
[MyAttribute]
public void MyTest()
{
    // This will be executed with respect to number of rows in TestContext
}
```

Can we set the rows that we have created to TextContext?

Comment: The best way of reading and saving a DataTable to a file is to use the DataTable ReadXml() and WriteXml() methods.

Comment: @jdweng I'm trying to store DataTable in an object, type of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: You can't have the object DataRows without a DataTable with columns defined.  DataSource implies a DataTable.  The simpliest way of going from text to a DataTable is using XML format, but you can parse text into a DataTable using lots of different methods.

Comment: @jdweng, I have read the data from the Text File to a DataTable successfully.
The next thing I want to do is, set that DataTable to TestContext.
And, I'm implementing `MyAttribute` from `Attribute` `MyAttribute: Attribute`.

Comment: See following webpage.  I think you just need TestMethod. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527(v=vs.80).aspx